# Add previously ignored git files. git add -f not working

Tags: git, gitignore

I used

```
git status --ignored
```

To check which files were ignored as follows :

```
 git status --ignored
# On branch SIT
# Ignored files:
#   (use "git add -f <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#       web/sites/default/files/
```

So, that's fine. But when I use :

```
git add -f web/sites/default/files/
```

And then use "git status --ignored" again it shows the same file. Even after adding these to a commit.

Comment: Are you asking how to remove a file or directory from `.gitignore`?

Comment: What exactly does the second `git status --ignored` show? The exact same directory, or just some files in the directory?

Answer (score 4):

You probably need to add a file under that directory, rather than adding the directory on its own. To add all contents of that directory:

```
git add -f web/sites/default/files/*
```

I had a similar issue, although my issue was caused by a `git update-index --assume-unchanged` command that I had issued earlier without fully understanding it. In case someone arrives here for a similar reason, I solved my issue by executing:

```
git update-index --no-assume-unchanged <myfile>
git add <myfile>
```

Refer to the [git-update-index](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index) docs for more details.